# Timedelta object cannot be converted with astype()

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

A native Pandas `Timedelta()` (with version `0.20.3`), can't convert to a specific frequency with `astype()`, although the docs say it should be possible.  I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing.

From the [Timedelta docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion):

> Timedelta Series, TimedeltaIndex, and Timedelta scalars can be converted to other ‘frequencies’ by dividing by another timedelta, **or by astyping** to a specific timedelta type.

It's true that I can convert by division with another timedelta:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__ 
# 0.20.3

day = pd.Timedelta("1 day")
day / pd.Timedelta(1, "h") 
# 24.0
```

But `astype()` fails:

```
day.astype('timedelta64[h]')
# AttributeError: 'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

The example in the documentation doesn't actually use `pd.Timedelta()`, and that seems to be part of the issue.  Instead, it uses `Series(date_range)` subtraction and `datetime.timedelta` (which seems a little funny given there's a native Pandas `Timedelta()`).

```
# This example is used in the Timedelta docs.
import datetime
td = pd.Series(pd.date_range('20130101', periods=4)) - pd.Series(pd.date_range('20121201', periods=4))
td[2] += datetime.timedelta(minutes=5, seconds=3)
td[3] = np.nan

td
0   31 days 00:00:00
1   31 days 00:00:00
2   31 days 00:05:03
3                NaT
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
# ...
td.astype('timedelta64[s]')
Out[75]: 
0    2678400.0
1    2678400.0
2    2678703.0
3          NaN
dtype: float64
```

The type of `day` from my example, however, is different:

```
type(day)
# <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timedelta'>
```

I haven't yet dug into the `tslib` source to figure out what's going on under the hood - hoping someone can clear up the seeming discrepancy between what's going on in the docs and what I'm trying to do here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`pd.Timedelta` doesn't have a the method `astype` while `pd.TimedeltaIndex` does.

```
pd.to_timedelta([day]).astype('timedelta64[h]')[0]

24
```

Comment: This solution does not work. `AttributeError: 'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'astype'`

Answer (score 0):

```
df['timedelta'] = df['timedelta'].apply(pd.to_timedelta)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.